# Best|Useful tools for ASP.NET/C# Devs?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What tools do you use to develop .net apps? Things that make life easier|quicker. Fiddler was just recommended to me but I'm not sure how it works yet, though it looks interesting. I also use Notepad++ as a quick text editor. Aside from that, it's just VS studio for me.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180939/net-must-have-development-tools - There is a very exhaustive of tools there. Not everything is ASP.net specific but you can pick what you need

Comment: Yeah, this question has been asked several times before.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you need. My setup includes:

- Visual Studio
- Visual SVN
- TeamCity
- nAnt
- JetBrains Resharper

Answer (score 5):

The 'best', I would say, includes:

- [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm) - decompiler, lets you view source on dlls that you didn't write
- [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/) - Clipboar manager. Just try it for a while, you won't know how you ever lived without it.
- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) for version control (many like Team Foundation Server, but it's expensive)
- [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) - building LINQ queries
- [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) - Compare two files for changes, merging differences
- [xUnit](http://www.codeplex.com/xunit) (or the slightly more popular NUnit[link text](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nunit/)) for unit testing
- [Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/) for graphics
- [Power Commands](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands) for Visual Studio

Those a my favourite general .net tools - there are more that I would use for specific situations. Of note is [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) for error handling/reporting in asp.net environments. Also, look at resharper, which is popular, but of which, I'm not a great fan.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from [LINQpad](http://linqpad.net) & [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which I can highly recommend, three I don't see mentioned yet are:

- Microsoft [WebMatrix](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/06/introducing-webmatrix.aspx) which includes IIS Express, SQL Compact Edition and the fastest way to get up and running with quick n' dirty ASP.NET code.
- Microsoft [Visual Web Developer 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) A step up from WebMatrix, a slightly heavier download, but worth it for the Intellisense.
- [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/) Often overlooked if working with JSON.

Answer (score 2):

And also,

[PokeIn](http://pokein.codeplex.com) - Server push (comet ajax) for ASP.NET / Mono

[MonoDevelop & Mono](http://www.mono.org) - Your second best friend on the Linux side ( the first one is QT :) )

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on what you need, and how much you dig into stuff. These are some tools which are an absolute must for me.

- Notepad++ - Amazingly powerful tabbed editor. [Free]
- Expression Studio - Good for Silverlight, WPF, Encoding/Decoding media, Designing web sites. Not free [Trial Available]
- Snagit - Screen capture utility. Not free
- Fiddler - HTTP Debugging Proxy [Free]
- Process Monitor [Free, you can use it see Locks, Access Issues, Registry and File Access]
- Process Explorer [Free, you can replace your Task Manager with it]
- Debug View [Free. See the debug output from any EXE from most of the languages, something like... System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write["Hi!"] without installing Visual Studio]
- WinDBG [Good for post production debugging. Free, but a little difficult to learn and master]
- Debug Diagnostics [Free, Capture dumps for any process]
- Network Monitor [Free network capturing tool]
- Reflector [Free utility to help you see the code of any .NET assembly]
- Bulk Rename Utility [A free utility that will help you rename bunch of files at one shot]
- WinMerge [Free, compare two files]
- Foxit Reader [Free, PDF reader... much much much faster than Adobe Reader.]

Hope this helps,
Rahul